# Django site administration can't manage data models

Tags: python, django

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin 
admin.autodiscover()
...
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

settings.py has active the admin module:

```
'django.contrib.admin',
```

but the site administration page only have "site"、"auth" categories , i can find my models here.

I have an django app named "testapp".

Any one can help ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to [register your models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) to the admin:

**testapp/admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from testapp.models import MyModel1, MyModle2


admin.site.register(MyModel1)
admin.site.register(MyModel2)
```